# How to run a command in background job and wait for result in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, background-process, job-control

How can I spawn a process for a particular command and while it is running capture its output?

For example I want to perform `dd` on a block and while it is doing its job and producing status message , I do something else with the output of the dd progress. I tired the script below but it never stops printing:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=32768 status=progress)&

while [ -z "$data" ]; do
 echo "waiting for data..." "${data}"
 # Do something else while $data is not returned
 sleep 0.1
done
```

I have made some progress but still not the thing I want.

```
    #! /bin/bash
    
    varFileDone=$(mktemp)
    varFileOutput=$(mktemp)
    
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=4096 \
count=32768 status=progress 2<&1 >> $varFileOutput && echo 1 > $varFileDone &
    pid=$(pidof dd)
    
    while [[ ! -s $varFileDone ]];
    do
    
    data=$(cat $varFileOutput)
    echo "----->" "$data"
    if [[ -s $data ]];
      then
        echo "we have data"
        echo $data | cut -d"," -f3
      else
        echo "no data yet!"
      fi
      sleep 0.2
    done
```

Comment: This question over on Stack Overflow seems to have some answers that may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017805/bash-capture-output-of-command-run-in-background

Comment: You're writing the data to `/dev/null`, what are you expecting to get in `$data`?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is just an example, I want to get the output of dd as its doing its job

Comment: @DEKKER This example only outputs some summary information at the very end of processing. Had you used a command that produced a steady stream of output, what would you expected to see and get in $data? Would you expect to see a status message from your loop at regular intervals, or only when there are long pauses, and would you expect to accumulate _all_ output in $data (even if this is gigabytes of data), or only the data since the last status output from your loop?

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right, I forgot to add `status=progress` at the end of dd. What I want to have is capture the progress and cut some specific field of the progress report and feed it somewhere else. I updated the question with more detail

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. Your use of setting a variable in the asynchronous environment does not quite work here, since the value of the variable is never available to the original environment.

The asynchronous call using ampersand `&` could be substituted with `coproc`. I suggest checking out the man page for bash, because there are a few tools with this format.

Example use:

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc COPROC ($(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=32768))

while [[ $COPROC ]]; do  
sleep 0.1
echo waiting!  
done

wait # unnecessary, but proves the asynchronous processes are actually complete
echo "Task done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=32768 & 2>&1 > /tmp/tmp
pid=$(ps|grep dd|awk '{print $1}')
while [[ ! "" = "$pid" ]]
do     
    # Do something else while dd is still writing

    grep "," /tmp/tmp | grep -v "+"|awk '{$2" "$3}'
done
```

Comment: I don't know why you're using `grep` and `ps`. You have the PID of the background process in `$!`.

Comment: I saw your edit. My advice would be `pid=$!`, and then use `while kill -0 "$pid"` to loop  while the PID is valid. Note that the `kill` command there will only tell you that the PID is _valid_, but it won't tell you whether it's the correct process (but neither did your `ps`+`grep` thing).

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to see `dd` command output, you can just add a redirection like this:

`data=$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=4096 count=32768 2>&1 /dev/null)`

`2>&1` is used to redirect output AND errors.

Just modify the output you want (replace `/dev/null` by any other file). You can check the output generated during the process using `tail` command, ie `tail -f /your/output/file`.

Comment: Hi, sadly this does not help.... I wan to have the command inside the script itself to be in background! not the script itself

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I added a redirection of the output. I hope it will be better like that...